# Retrieve hostname -f within YAML(yml)

Tags: yaml, yum, hostname

I've got a config `.cfg` file that has the hostname hard coded in it.  I'm trying to find a way for the hostname to be gotten locally (dynamically) by running a command similar to `hostname -f` to have it configure the variable in the .cfg, without running a script, like python, to write the config file ahead time.  Is it possible to run a 'yum' command that gets the hostname to use in the YAML/yml file?

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to Wikipedia, I think I found out why no one is helping me with this:

[Wiki YAML -> Security](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YAML#Security)

> Security
>   YAML is purely a data representation language and thus has no executable commands. While validation and safe parsing is inherently possible in any data language, implementation is such a notorious pitfall that YAML's lack of an associated command language may be a relative security benefit.
>
> However, YAML allows language-specific tags so that arbitrary local objects can be created by a parser that supports those tags. Any YAML parser that allows sophisticated object instantiation to be executed opens the potential for an injection attack. Perl parsers that allow loading of objects of arbitrary class create so-called "blessed" values. Using these values may trigger unexpected behavior, e.g. if the class uses overloaded operators. This may lead to execution of arbitrary Perl code.
>
> The situation is similar for Python or Ruby parsers. According to the PyYAML documentation